# How to send data over a raw ethernet socket using sendto and winsock.h with the cygwin compiler on windows

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I'd like to send a raw Ethernet packet.

I'm using Eclipse and the Compiler cygwin with the winsock.h file and the libws_32.a library from cygwin.

In linux I used the `sockaddr_ll` for the struct that contains the address of the target socket. Is there an equivalent sockaddr struct in windows?

This sockaddr struct should have the same parameters like the `sockaddr_ll` struct in linux.

Below you can see a code example:

```
WSAData wsaData;

WORD DLLVersion=MAKEWORD(2,2);

if (WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData) != 0) // If WASStartup returns anything other than 0, then that means an error has occured
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL,"Winsock startup failed", "error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    return 0;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/* Creat a Raw Socket
 * The socket function causes a socket descriptor and any related resources
 * to be allocated and bound to a specific transport-service provider.
 * Winsock will utilize the first available service provider that supports
 * the requested combination of address family, socket type and protocol parameters
 */


SOCKET rawSocket = socket(AF_UNSPEC, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW ); //IPPROTO_RAW nicht sicher ob dieser Parameter möglich ist https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
if (rawSocket == INVALID_SOCKET )
{
    cout << "Fehlercode:"<< WSAGetLastError()<<" Failed to create RawSocket on L2Windows. Try to Run as Admin." << endl;
    return 0;
}
else
{
    cout << "RawSocket created." << endl;
}

//config destination 
struct sockaddr_??? dest; //here are my question
```

Comment: Windows just doesn't expose ethernet sockets the same way Linux does.

Comment: Use `SOCK_RAW` -> More info on this struct [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548(v=vs.85).aspx) . Also keep in mind that there are restrictions on Raw sockets on certain Windows OS'

Comment: Hello  mutantkeyboard
I red this document already but my problem is that i like to specify my own protocol at Layer 4. Do you no anithing helpful ?